# Is it OK to ask a question about naming conventions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, site-recommendation, software-engineering-se

I understand that naming conventions for code have an element of personal preference, and can be subjective and argumentative, which isn't the goal of these sites.

But, I'm really looking for feedback on demonstrating that some current naming conventions I'm forced to use hurt readability and do more harm than good.  Where should I ask this question? Stack Overflow? Or does this belong on the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site?

Comment: I will tell you before anyone suggests it: do *not* ask on English. [They're not there to be a tool for naming your classes](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/is-python-a-snake-or-a-programming-language-if-the-latter-why-is-it-choking-my).

Comment: @Grace, if you hadn't included that link, I would've thought you were joking, due to the sheer ridiculousness of the concept.

Comment: The tag [naming-standards](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming-standards) is being used on SE.SE. I [answered](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/377265/166351) one such question myself. Any such answer should be backed up by linking to the naming convention Standards for the question being asked, and not simply be one person's opinion or experience. Note that there is an answer that is nine years old from the moderator (edited an hour ago) discouraging asking there in most but not every circumstance; and that he'll act on flags if they appear.

Comment: Thing is: the human brain can adapt. Seriously, I *hated* the java style I was forced to use in my job. Nothing did make sense. After a few weeks, I adapted. In the next job, I took me again a few weeks to forget the nonsense, and come back to something that resembled more how the rest of the world is doing things. So, be careful where you put your energy. (but sure, fighting people who want to force you to say use hungarian notation ... might be a good thing)

Answer (score 13):

Please don't ask on Software Engineering.

There are already several questions on this subject, none of which are particularly useful.

The most important thing about a naming convention is that you are consistent and follow (broadly) industry practice for your language, so really there's nothing much more to say.

Comment: What about "What is the industry practice for naming <element:foo> in <language:bar>"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I should have done some searching on Programmers first. Basically, I want to elaborate on [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/66205/annoying-or-idiotic-naming-conventions/66223#66223). Does this warrant a new question?

Comment: @Joachim - that *might* be OK, but it *is* something that's fairly easily discoverable so it would depend on who saw the question first ;)

Comment: @wsanville - why do you want to elaborate on that answer?

Comment: I want to figure out for sure that other programmers find that style of naming extremely insane and unreadable.

Comment: @wsanville - I don't think it would really be a constructive question, but if you really want to ask it go ahead. I'll only respond to any flags it might earn. I can't speak for the other moderators though - they might not agree with me.

Answer (score 3):

Some example questions, to judge by precedent below. I picked such that have considerable upvotes, though a lot such questions are downvoted (the choice is not representative):

- [What is the naming convention in Python for variable and function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)
- [Why shouldn't I use "Hungarian Notation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933)
- [What is the benefit of not using Hungarian notation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102689/what-is-the-benefit-of-not-using-hungarian-notation)
- [Naming conventions: camelCase versus underscore_case ? what are your thoughts about it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/naming-conventions-camelcase-versus-underscore-case-what-are-your-thoughts-ab)
- [For a boolean field, what is the naming convention for its getter/setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322648/for-a-boolean-field-what-is-the-naming-convention-for-its-getter-setter)
- [What is a good naming convention for vars, methods, etc in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706379/what-is-a-good-naming-convention-for-vars-methods-etc-in-c)
- [Coding Conventions - Naming Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069743/coding-conventions-naming-enums)
- [Interface naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681700/interface-naming-convention/32571112)
- [Generic type parameter naming convention for Java (with multiple chars)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900881/generic-type-parameter-naming-convention-for-java-with-multiple-chars)
- [Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)
- [Is there a standard naming convention for XML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442529/is-there-a-standard-naming-convention-for-xml-elements)
- [Ruby naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600305/ruby-naming-conventions)

You need to judge for yourself if your question is interesting enough. As you can see some old questions got many upvotes, but several also got closed as off-topic.

For SO, you can consider whether your question is a "*practical*, *answerable* *problem* that is unique to software development".

Answer (score -4):

I think Programmers is the best location to ask such a question.  As ChrisF's answer indicates, the question probably already exists and a new one would just be closed as a duplicate.   If you could be specific enough in your question it might stay open, but you most likely would get a bunch of subjective answers that would not help you much.

Comment: See the comment on ChrisF's answer, does that sound specific enough?

Comment: @wsanville, yes, but will I wonder if such a question will provide any meaningful answers.

Comment: Where, honestly, this isn't subjective at all. The real answer is: there are conventions that simply do not make sense any more (like hungarian notation, which is no longer useful due to the fact that any decent editor can nowadays tell you the type of your variables, so no need to hardcode it). And for the rest: the objective answer is that such conventions are subjective, and therefore should try to follow "what everyone else does", combined with "be consistent".